# Checking port value using CDATA in WiX

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, cdata

I want to have a port number validation in my WiX installer. Using one of codes below, I try to check if a database port has a value between 1024 and 65535:

```
1. <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidPortNumber"><![CDATA[(DATABASE_PORT < 1024 OR DATABASE_PORT > 65535)]]></Publish>
2. <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidPortNumber"><![CDATA[(DATABASE_PORT < "1024" OR DATABASE_PORT > "65535")]]></Publish>
```

But none of them do not publish a spawn dialog if the user writes a port number less than 1024. For value greater than 65535 everything works good.

The port number is set in:

```
<Control Id="DatabasePortText" Type="MaskedEdit" X="20" Y="120" Width="50" Height="15" Property="DATABASE_PORT" Text="######"/>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your property is treated as string, thus `<` and `>` don't really make sense in the way that it should.

You have two choices:

- Use `Edit` control and set `Integer` attribute as yes:  `<Control Type="Edit" Integer="yes" .../>`. This will make sure that property is treated as integer.
- Use `MaskedEdit`, and when you press `Next` button, a custom action will be executed which can convert string property into integer property.

Comment: Also does not work. I edited my question, added code with control where property DATABASE_PORT is set. Maybe it causes bug.